# SOLVED isAuthenticated always returns false

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

So I'm creating login system with nodejs and passport js, so in my login route after user logins isAuthenticated returns true

```
router.post('/login', guestMiddleware, (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      req.session.user = user
      if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        console.log('isAuthenticated')
      } else {
        console.log('not authenticated')
      }

      return res.redirect('/homepage')
    })
  })(req, res, next)
})
```

the code above returns isAuthenticated

but when I'm redirecting user isAuthenticated returns false

```
app.get('/homepage', (req, res) => {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    console.log('isAuthenticated')
  } else {
    console.log('not authenticated')
  }
  req.user = req.session.user
  res.send(`welcome ${req.user.username}`)
})
```

the code above returns not authentificated

tried using other versions of pasport, tried forsing isAuthenticated to be true

Sorry for wasting your time, but I solved this problem, I was working on it for like 3 days, not finding solutions on internet, so I decided to post a question here, but after posting I tried changing something at deserialize and it worked

Anyways I'll be happy to help people with the same problem here

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to add the middleware to the `/homepage` as well

Comment: I added it as well, but middleware works form isAuthenticated, and if it returns false it reditects me back to login

Comment: Please tell is what you did. Thanks @YoungTea

Comment: If you will provide me your code Ill help you